# circuitikz: Change position of label and arrow

Tags: circuitikz

I have put together a equivalent circuit model of a battery in Latex and circuitikz, but I can not change the position of two elements.
So I would like to have the arrow and label of the voltage source on the left side instead of the right. I tried "mirror" and a >/< by the v of the label, but it did not change.
Additionally I would like the arrow and label of V_bat on the right instead of the left like it is now.

How do I accomplish this?

Here is the code and a picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to[american voltage source, v=$V_{OCV}$] (0,-4);
            \draw (0,0) to [short] (2,0);
            \draw (2,0) to [short] (2,1);
            \draw (2,0) to [short] (2,-1);
            \draw (2,1) to[R=$R(SoC)$] (5,1);
            \draw (2,-1) to[C=$C(SoC)$] (5,-1);
            \draw (5,-1) to [short] (5,1);
            \draw (5,0) to [short, -o] (6,0);
            \draw (0,-4) to [short, -o] (6,-4);
            \draw (6,0) to [open, v=$V_{Bat}$] (6,-4);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Please do what @JoséCarlosSantos is suggesting. Which voltage option is in force (i.e., how you call the `circuitikz` package) is important to answer correctly...

Comment: Please see the updated post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The side on which the labels are shown in voltages is controlled by the modifiers `_` and `^` (the ones you tried, `<` and `>`, control the direction). So change the two voltages to:

```
    (0,0) to[american voltage source, v_=$V_{OCV}$] 
    ...
    (6,0) to [open, v^=$V_{Bat}$] (6,-4)
```

[image]

In addition, you should really use one of the two modern voltage directions (in your case, `EFvoltages`, I think); the default is the old `nooldvoltages`, which is not completely coherent (see the manual in section 5.2 for details). Moreover, you should try to use a continuous path when possible — if you zoom in, the wires in your circuits join like this:

[image]

So, for example (but this can be muchly improved using relative and named coordinates):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[EFvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[american voltage source, v_=$V_{OCV}$]
        (0,-4) to [short, -o] (6,-4);
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1)
        to[R=$R(SoC)$] (5,1) -- (5,0)
        to[short, -o] (6,0);
    \draw (2,0) -- (2,-1)
        to[C=$C(SoC)$] (5,-1) -- (5,0);
    \draw (6,0) to [open, v^=$V_{Bat}$] (6,-4);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Zoom in an see the difference!)